# Make returned JSON readable by javascript in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, flask

I am developing a simple app in which the HTML interface sends some data to a Python Flask Server, which makes some graphs and a table. I want to return the graph base64 urls AND the HTML code for the table all in one response. I figured I should just put them into an array and jsonify it. Here is the line causing me issues, where `table` is plain HTML code generated by pandas and `pic_hash` is a base64 URL to the graph PNG.

```
return jsonify(table, pic_hash)
```

In the javascript, when I reference the 0th index of the response, I get a single `<`. I'm sure this is because pandas uses double quotes in the attributes when using `to_html()`.

**How can I make this just a simple array with two items, one the HTML code without escapes or double quotes, and the other a valid base64 URL?**

Comment: use simple `[ ]` to create list `jsonify( [table, pic_hash] ) `.

Comment: BTW `jsonify` converts data to string and it adds escapes - after you get it in JavaScript you have to convert it back from string to normal data - and it should remove escapes. It seems you get string and you didn't convert it back to data. And now you use this string as array and index `0` gives you first char in this string.

Comment: you didn't show code which you use to get data in JavaScript but some libraries should automatically convert JSON string to data. OR you have to do it manually [JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)

Comment: Thank you for this. I had indeed forgotten to do JSON.parse(), that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonify` converts data to string and it adds escapes - to create correct `JSON` data.

In `JavaScript` you have to convert it back from string to normal data and it should remove escapes. See [JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)

In `jQuery` to can use [getJSON()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to get data from server already converted from string to data.